# Powershell comparison of text file

Tags: powershell, readfile

I'm just wondering if it's possible to compare two text file and check if there's a difference between them? What I mean is like this,

For example I have text1.txt :

```
123
456
789
000
```

and I have text2.txt :

```
123,test,input,bake
789,input,cake,bun
```

Expected output :

```
456 does not exist in text2.txt
000 does not exist in test2.txt
```

I'm new to this language (Powershell) I just have this code that getting the content of two text file and I don't know how to compare it.

```
$file1 = "C:\test\folder\test1.txt";
$file2 = "C:\test\folder\test2.txt";

$getfile1 = Get-Content $file1
$getfile2 = Get-Content $file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get you started:

```psh
# $file1 will be an array with each element containing the line contents
$file1 = get-content .\text1.txt

# $file2 will be an array with each element containing the line contents just like $file1
$file2 = get-content .\text2.txt

# This splits each line of $file2 on the comma and grabs the first element and assigns it to the $file2FirstPart array.
$file2FirstPart = $file2 | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(',')[0] }

# This uses the Compare-Object cmdlet to compare the arrays.
$comparision = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1 -DifferenceObject $file2FirstPart -Passthru

# This just displays the string you wanted to display for the comparison results
$comparison | ForEach-Object { "$($_) does not exist in text file 2" }
```

Good luck learning powershell!

Comment: I was debating changing % to `ForEach-Object` as well and explaining the alias since the user was new.....

Comment: Thanks bunch for the explanation guys! I realize now how powerful the powershell is :)

Comment: @Matt - You're right, I shouldn't have used an alias to begin with since the  OP was new, I will update it.